# How do I find the moment of inertia of a regular $n$-gon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, moment-of-inertia

Of a regular $n$-gon with radius $R$ and mass $M$. Any hint to solving would also be acceptable. The result I'm looking for is $$I_{CM} = (1/2) MR^2 (1 - (2/3) \sin^2(\pi/n)).$$

Comment: Can you find the moment of inertia of a triangle?

Comment: @RobinEkman No, I have not tried calculating it. Can you explain how I would go about doing that? Better yet, can you explain how to go about solving the problem originally asked, please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divide the $n$-sided regular polygon into $2n$ right-angled triangles.  Calculate the moment of inertia for a triangle with the appropriate dimensions and appropriate mass rotating about the appropriate point, which will require a much easier integration than would calculating the moment of inertia for the whole polygon at once.  Then multiply the triangle's moment of inertia by $2n$.

To calculate the moment of inertia for just the one triangle, use the integral

$$I_P = \int_V \rho(\mathbf{r})\,\mathbf{r}^2 \, dV\ ,$$

as described in the [Calculating moment of inertia about an axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Calculating_moment_of_inertia_about_an_axis) Wikipedia article section.  With an appropriate choice of parameterization, doing the integration will only require being able to integrate polynomials.